# Initializing an unique_ptr though a constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class BaseShader {
        std::unique_ptr<HandleInterface> handle_;
    public:
        BaseShader();
        BaseShader(std::unique_ptr<HandleInterface> handle_ptr);
```

.cpp

```
BaseShader::BaseShader(std::unique_ptr<HandleInterface> handle_ptr) {
    handle_.reset(handle_ptr.get());
}
//BaseHandle implements HandleInterface
BaseShader::BaseShader():BaseShader(std::make_shared<BaseHandle>()) {
}
```

How would I initialize my unique_ptr `handle_` correctly?

I want to use it like this `BaseShader s(std::make_shared<BaseHandle>());`

Clang tells me

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'BaseShader'
BaseShader::BaseShader():BaseShader(std::make_shared<BaseHandle>()) {
                         ^          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I probably messed it up.

1.) Is my constructor argument correct? `BaseShader::BaseShader(std::unique_ptr<HandleInterface> handle_ptr)`

2.) If 1.) is true is `handle_.reset(handle_ptr.get());` the correct way of initializing my handle_ unique_ptr?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, you should simply `std::move` from the argument of the constructor to `handle_` in the member initialization list:

```
BaseShader::BaseShader(std::unique_ptr<HandleInterface> handle_ptr)
  : handle_(std::move(handle_ptr))
{ }
```

Second, `std::make_shared` will give you a `shared_ptr`, when you want a `unique_ptr`. Unfortunately, there is no `std::make_unique` ([yet](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3656.htm)), so you'll have to do it like this:

```
BaseShader::BaseShader()
  : BaseShader(std::unique_ptr<BaseHandle>(new BaseHandle()))
{ }
```

This will only work if `BaseHandle` is derived from `HandleInterface`.

Comment: @hmjd Copy constructor of what? I don't think I'm copying anything here.

Comment: @hmjd It should be taking it by value. The argument will be move constructed from whatever rvalue the user passes.

Comment: Ok, guess I'm not fully understanding something about move.

Comment: I get the following error at `handle_(std::move(handle_ptr))` - `error: member initializer 'handle_' does not name a non-static data member or base class: handle_(std::move(handle_ptr))` What does this mean?

Comment: @sftrabbit No I really want to have a unique ptr to HandleInterface. I want to change the behavior at runtime so any class that implements HandleInterface should be assignable to my unique_ptr. In this case BaseHandle implements HandleInterface. Is this a problem in c++?

Comment: @MaikKlein Are you sure it's actually called `handle_`? The compiler is not finding any member called `handle_`. And oh sorry, I didn't realise that the inheritance was that way around. I expected `BaseHandle` to be the base class.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update for modern C++

In response to Joseph's magnificent answer, here's an update on his second point:

> Second, `std::make_shared` will give you a `shared_ptr`, when you want a `unique_ptr`. Unfortunately, there is no `std::make_unique` ([yet](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3656.htm)), so you'll have to do it like this...

Note that there is now a `std::make_unique` method:

> **std::make_unique**
>
> Constructs an object of type T and wraps it in a std::unique_ptr.
>
> 1) Constructs a non-array type T. The arguments args are passed to the constructor of T. This overload only participates in overload resolution if T is not an array type. The function is equivalent to:
>
> `unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...))`
>
> 2) Constructs an array of unknown bound T. This overload only participates in overload resolution if T is an array of unknown bound. The function is equivalent to:
>
> `unique_ptr<T>(new typename std::remove_extent<T>::type[size]())`
>
> 3) Construction of arrays of known bound is disallowed.

[Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique)