# C++ Inheritance and copy constructors, for non-trivial classes (deep copy)

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor

On request by M.M I have re-posted this question.

This question is about inheritance, not the rule of 3, as YSC previously thought.

I have a class (two, actually)

```
class A
{
private: // [!] ?
    int *a;
public:
    A(const A& other) : a{new int[...]}
    {
        std::copy(...)
    }
}

class B : public A
{
private:
    int *b;
public:
    B(const B& other) : b{new int [...]}
    {
        std::copy(...)
    }
}
```

These are non-trivial classes, obviously. We need to deep copy the data in the copy constructor.

An example usage

```
int main()
{
    B binst;
    B binst2(binst); // [LABEL 1]
}
```

How does one write a copy constructor for `class B`, so that the value of `int *a` will be copied correctly at `[LABEL 1]`?

Someone else mentioned implicit type conversion between classes. But I don't yet know what that precisely means. (HOW will the implicit conversion be done.)

I'm sure this is an easy question, but I couldn't seem to find the answer.

Comment: Have you tried calling the super class copy constructor on the sub class copy constructor? `B(const B& other) : A(other), b ...`

Comment: @Nadir Sure, I can blindly try this and hope it works, or I can ask a question and I can try to learn something (ie; do it the proper way) ... just because it compiles don't mean it's doing what I think it's doing

Comment: why wouldn't it be the propper way to call the parent contructor?

Comment: @user3728501 Regardless of whether or not it doesn't what you _want_, it's what you _need_ to do. Subclasses should call parent class ctors.

Comment: @Nadir The arguments are different types. I don't know what happens here

Comment: @erip see above comment

Comment: The argument is not different, The argument in A ctor is an instance of A, and B, by inheritance, is an instance of A

Comment: B is an A. It seems like you're missing something about inheritance. Maybe [this](http://ideone.com/mmlaqX) will help you. It's not exactly what you want, but you can play with it.

Comment: Your example should not even compile. It should fail with the following error: no matching function for call to 'A::A()'.

Comment: @MohamadElghawi Aside from obvious code omissions, it seems fine to me.

Comment: @erip I think he is talking about the line `B(const B& other) : b{new int}`  . This will fail to compile because `A` has no default constructor (and `A` is not an aggregate); `B`'s ctor-initializer list must specify an initializer for `A` .  `B b;` would actually fail to compile too, for similar reasons.

Comment: @M.M Ah, understood. I thought we were assuming OP wrote a default ctor with boring behavior, so it was omitted. :)

Answer (score 4):

In this design, the copy constructor would be:

```
B(const B& other) : A(other), b{new int [...]}
```

You invoke `A`'s copy-constructor to initialize the `A` member of this `B` object.

Note: A better design is to have each resource-managing object be self-contained. For example, if `B` actually had two pointer members initialized as `b{new int}, c{new int}` then your code cannot recover from an exception being thrown by the second `new`.

For example:

```
struct IntManager
{
    int *i;
    // here put your copy-constructors etc. etc.
};

struct A
{
    IntManager a;
};

struct B : A
{
    IntManager b;
};
```

This is called *Rule of Zero*. You avoid having to write any of the special functions for A or B (with the exception of constructors that are not copy/move constructors).  So your code remains simple and there is no way to get it wrong, and you do not have code duplication everywhere like you will in your `A` and `B` examples.

NB. `std::unique_ptr<int>` might serve the role you need your `int *` to do , if so then use that to avoid reinventing the wheel. When pointers have ownership semantics it is good to indicate that .  Raw pointers should only ever be used to point to things that are owned by someone else (and even then, try to avoid it).

Comment: FWIW, if OP is unfamiliar with smart pointers, it might be good to mention that in initialization lists the val will need to be moved. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492044/initializing-an-unique-ptr-though-a-constructor)'s a good reference. +1

Comment: @erip Yeah that is true. `unique_ptr` could not be a drop-in replacement for `IntManager` because it doesn't have a copy-constructor that clones the data (which I guess is what OP wants). But `IntManager` could have a `unique_ptr` member , plus a custom copy-constructor.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` for arrays, or `std::vector<int>`.